# Sidebar Positioning Issue

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin, sidebar

I have a sidebar on my site page the aligns completely to the left but I want there to be some space from the left and the sidebar like on the site below:

https://www.artweb.com/artwork/search

Here is the CSS code for the sidebar:

```
:focus {
outline: none;
}
.row {
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
}

.side-menu {
position: fixed;
margin-left: 50px;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #f8f8f8;
border-right: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.side-menu .navbar {
border: none;
}
.side-menu .navbar-header {
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.side-menu .navbar-nav .active a {
background-color: transparent;
margin-right: -1px;
border-right: 5px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.side-menu .navbar-nav li {
display: block;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
}
.side-menu .navbar-nav li a {
padding: 15px;
}
```

Also a JFiddle with the HTML and preview of how it looks now:
https://jsfiddle.net/sgroL45L/

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: yes I am using it

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/101100 check this link for better work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please include below snippet

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
 left:10px;
}
```

Comment: This didn't do anything to it